# How to change default contact template

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts

When i create a new contact and go to insert a phone number the default category for this is "Home", I don't have anyone's home phone number now as this is 2015 not 1999. How can i change this default so that the category that appears first is "Mobile" ? IOS 8.1.3

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a feature in iOS 8 or iOS 9.

If you don't want a new number to be categorized as "home" you need to tap and change it. Luckily, third party apps can and do provide more customized interfaces to your contact database.

I would start with a tool like [Interact](https://itunes.apple.com/app/id1045605097?mt=8) for setting up a more flexible default contact addition interface as well as extending concepts such as groups and smart parsing of contact details.

The time you save with one-tap contact addition and share sheet access to this app will more than make up for the expense and effort needed to have a better tool for contact management than ships with the OS.